# Adding points to an existing linestring

Tags: openlayers

Is it possible to add points to an existing linestring in openlayers? I have a stream of points coming from the server that I wish to draw when they arrive on the client. Currently, the only way I can see to do this is to draw a single line from the last point that I received to the new point each time a new point comes in, like so:

```
Drawer.prototype.drawPoint = function(point)
{
    var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([this.lastPoint, point]);
    var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, null, this.style);
    this.lineLayer.addFeatures([lineFeature]);
    this.lastPoint = point;
}
```

This seems inefficient. Obviously I could keep an array of all of the points and redraw the whole line each time a new point comes in, but that seems inefficient too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString` has a method `addPoint(point, index)` through the `OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPoint` class that it derives from, take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Geometry/MultiPoint.js).

So your solution should be as simple as:

```
line.addPoint(point); //second parameter(index) is optional
```

You will probably need to call `redraw()` method on the layer as well.

Comment: That's the one. I've come to the conclusion that the docs on the OpenLayers website are worthless! (http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.7/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/LineString-js.html). Needs to show inherited methods as well.

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend referencing source code instead of documentation. It's well structured and it's easy to find things there. You will also often find comments that clarify how things work that you'll never find in documentation.

Comment: In OL3, this is called `appendCoordinate` now. ([documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.18.2/apidoc/ol.geom.LineString.html#appendCoordinate))